# Keep in sync with the database

Tags: python, mysql

I’m currently making an app using Python and `MySql` that can be used in a restaurant. The app is a `TKinter` GUI that makes changes in the database(such as order id’s, active orders, etc). The current version takes information from the databases and creates a class object for each entry(food, drinks, tables). My question is: is there any way to keep the classes and the database in sync? I modified an order status in the app, and I want it modified instantly in the database. Do I need to write code for each action that takes place and commit them to the database? Or can I just use a script to keep everything in sync automatically?